# Unable to run scheduled tasks using command line using Schtasks

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run a scheduled tasks hourly using schtasks by executing following command

> schtasks /create /tn "my task" /tr C:\GTnE\Sch.vbs /sc once /sd 2016/05/08 /st 10:26:00

Task gets created successfully but doesn't run.

I have also tried to run it through wscript

```
 Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell") strCmd="SCHTASKS
 /create /tn Mytask1 /tr C:\GTnE\Sch.vbs /sc ONCE /sd 2016/05/08 /st
 10:47" result = oShell.run(strCmd, 1, True) ' check the result to see
 if the command was successful If result = 0 Then
     MsgBox "SUCCESS!" Else
     MsgBox "Task creation failed" End If
```

Comment: Try to have wscript or cscript run that vbs

Comment: I have updated the wscript i used to schedule the task but it didn't run !

Comment: I meant schtask.exe xscript.exe sch.vbs

Comment: are you refering to something like this : schtasks /create /tn "my task" /tr "cscript c:\GTnE\Sch.vbs" /sc once /sd 2016/05/08 /st 11:11:00

Comment: Yes. Just try,  it should do no harm

Comment: Yeah i tried but didn't work